# Fortran and Matlab: Change the data format

Tags: matlab, format, fortran

I have saved my job in Fortran with the following format

```
OPEN(50,file ='h.dat',form='formatted')
  WRITE(50,'(101F12.6)')(u(k),k=1,nx)
CLOSE(50)
```

Since nx = 201, the data is saved in 2 lines. The first line has 101 columns, the second one has 100 columns. Therefore, MATLAB can not read h.dat with the following message “... must be the same as previous lines”.

Would it be possible to change this 2-line data to be 1-line data (201 columns) by using Matlab?

Comment: I have solved the problem.....

Answer (score 0):

hh = importdata('h.dat');

size(hh) % ans =   2   101

nx = 201;

p = 0;

for i = 1:2;

```
for j = 1:101;

    p = p+1;

    ha(p) = hh(i,j);

end
```

end

ha = ha(1:nx);

save haa.dat ha -ascii

But, I think, it is much easier to use Fortran to solve it...